# How to tell when a progressbar is done?

Tags: c#

I am using C# with WinForms. I am updating a progressBar. When the Value reaches it's maximum value, I would like it to display a messageBox.

Is there anyway for the progressBar to execute a method when it's full? Is so then some code sample or a link to the solution would be appreciated

```
   private void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar - and our label :)
    void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The progress percentage is a property of e
        int percentComplete = progressBarStatus.Value / progressBarStatus.Maximum;
        labelPercentComplete.Text = percentComplete.ToString() + "% Completed";

        //progressBarStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        //labelPercentComplete.Text = String.Format("Trade{0}", e.ProgressPercentage);
    } 

    private void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(progressBarStatus.Value == progressBarStatus.Maximum)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }


 public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                            (bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;
 }
```

Comment: You sound like that progress bar is not under your control. Since you are updating its value, you can check if that value is the maximum when updating, and display a message box accordingly.

Comment: The value of the progressBar is being updated from another Form. So how would I check (without continuously polling the progressBar) to get the value? The logic isn't hard its going to be if(progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum) { // do something }

Comment: It sounds like the architecture needs rethinking a little, and perhaps the other form should be raising some events you can listen to.  Or without this refactoring and to keep it similar to how it is now, put a function in your progress bar form that can be called from the other form when appropriate

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking but I'm not sure how to raise events. Using ObjC, I'd use KVO KVC to do this. Or NSNotificationCenter. I'm relatively new to C#

Comment: *How* is it updated from another form? You shouldn't expose controls, but some properties, then in setters you are able to *catch* when something is trying to *set* it. If you exposed the control, then only polling. Unless you create and expose *wrapper*.

Comment: The MessageBox should have which window as a parent? i.e. you want the method to be executed from where?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line, if(progressBarStatus.Value == progressBarStatus.Maximum). I guess if you are not updating this value, it will never reach maximum

Comment: @Pankaj I can see the progressbar being updated visually. It executes on launch when progressBar.value = 0. It doesn't run after the progress bar is being updated

Comment: Have you done this bgWorker.ReportProgress(100); in bgWorker_DoWork ?

Comment: No I haven't used that in my code. Do I need it? If so then were is that suppose to go?

Comment: if you use e.Result = true; in  bgWorker_DoWork,  then you will get a call in bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted, See my code below, I have tested it is it works completely fine

Comment: e.Result = true;// Tell that you are done [im done when it's 100% full.]

Comment: I also tried your suggestion. It's not firing when I want it to. It fires as soon as I call RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: Be aware that `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` and `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` are totally unrelated; you can set progress to 100% at any time and that does not make your progressBar “done”. You can invoke `RunWorkerCompleted` regardless of what your progress status is. Please please study [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) before going further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you do not want to do something when background worker completes, but you want to do something when progress bar reaches maximum... Ok, first, set your progressBarStatus maximum value, then you should try something like this:

```
    void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBarStatus.Maximum == e.ProgressPercentage)
        {
            // do whatever you want to do
        }
    }
```

and update progressBarStatus value from from another form.
Altough this may not the best way to do things, if this is really what you want, then do whatever makes you happy... :)

EDIT:
Ok, I added complete example of the program that works perfectly, with calling ProgressChanged event, and checking for the Maximum value correctly, when the Maximum value is reached, ProgressBar is getting restarted and the message is printed in the Output window, with bunch of comments (and bunch of typos of course :D ), please try this example, see how it works, and apply it to your problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BGWORKERAPP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgWorker.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;        // needed to be able to report progress
            bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;   // needed to be able to stop the thread using CancelAsync();
            bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
            bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

            // ProgressBar is added to the form manually, and here I am just setting some initial values
            progressBarStatus.Maximum = 100;
            progressBarStatus.Minimum = 0;
            progressBarStatus.Value = 0;
            progressBarStatus.Step = 10;
        }
        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)    // keep looping until user presses the "Stop" button
            {
                if (bgWorker.CancellationPending)   // if bgWorker.CancelAsync() is called, this CancelationPending token will be set,
                {                                   // and if statement will be true
                    bgWorker.CancelAsync();
                    return;     // Thread is getting canceled, RunWorkerCompleted will be called next
                }

                i++;    // add any value you want, I chose this value because of the test example...
                Thread.Sleep(1);    // give thread some time to report (1ms is enough for this example) - NECESSARY, 
                                    //WITHOUT THIS LINE, THE MAIN THREAD WILL BE BLOCKED!
                bgWorker.ReportProgress(i); // report progress (will call bw_ProgressChanged) - NECESSARY TO REPORT PROGRESS!
            }
        }
        int somethingTerrible = 1;  // used to do something terrible ;)
        void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // I added this "somethingTerrible" variable to make the ProgressChanged run all over again, even when e.ProgressPercentage value
            // is greater then the progressBarStatus.Maximum, but, you should call bw.CancelAsync() because the job should be finished.
            // Also, this code will give you Exception eventually, numbers are limited after all...
            if (somethingTerrible * progressBarStatus.Maximum == e.ProgressPercentage)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("THIS IS CALLED WHEN THE MAXIMUM IS REACHED");   // this will be printed in the Output window
                progressBarStatus.Value = 0; // progressBarStatus value is at the maximum, restart it (or Exception will be thrown)

                //bw.CancelAsync();   // used to stop the thread when e.ProgressPercentage is equal to progressBarMaximum, but in our
                                      // example, we just make the code keep running.
                                      // We should cancel bgWorker now because the work is completed and e.ProgressPercentage will
                                      // be greater then the value of the progressBarStatus.Maximum, but if you really want
                                      // you can do something like this to make the thread keep reporting without any errors (until numbers reach the limit)...
                somethingTerrible++;
            }
            else
            {
                progressBarStatus.Value++;  // increasing progressBarStatus.Value, until we get to the maximum.
            }
        }
        void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Worker completed");    // worker finished the task...
        }

        // Buttons are added to the Form manually as well
        private void runBgTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    // button on the Form to start the thread
        {
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();  // start the background worker (call DoWork)
        }

        private void stopBgTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   // button on the Form to stop the thread
        {
            bgWorker.CancelAsync(); // tell the background worker to stop (will NOT stop the thread immediately); the DoWork will be
                                    // called once again, but with CancelationPending token set to true, so the if statement
                                    // in the DoWork will be true and the thread will stop.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's correct but the method isn't firing. I added a breakpoint and a MessageBox.Show(). Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you need to report progress using [bgWorker.ReportProgress(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx), I added an edit, check it out...

Comment: Thanks for your code. I really appreciate it. I am observing something that is different than what I am expecting. So I have a form2 that processes an HTML page. Form2 is invisible and there are 5 Steps. At each step's completion, we report the progress back to Form1. However when the progressBar gets to it's maximum value (5), I want to kickstart another method to do something else. For now, lets assume its to pop up a messagebox saying "I'm done".

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should look at BackgroundWorker which is made specifically for this purpose. You will get Event RunWorkerCompleted when your work in finished. I am giving you a working example where you are copying lots of files.

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
bgWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerDoWork;
bgWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new BackgroundWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                (bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

void StartWork()
{ 
 // Start BackGround Worker Thread 
  bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}

void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //NOTE : DONT play with the UI thread here...
  // Do Whatever work you are doing and for which you need to show    progress bar
     CopyLotsOfFiles() // This is the function which is being run in the background
   e.Result = true;// Tell that you are done
}

void CopyLotsOfFiles()
{
  Int32 counter = 0;
  List<String> filestobeCopiedList = ...; // get List of files to be copied
  foreach (var file in filestobeCopiedList)
  {
       counter++;
      // Calculate percentage for Progress Bar
      Int32 percentage = (counter * 100) / filesCount;
      bgWorker.ReportProgress(percentage);

      // Files copy code goes here
  }
  bgWorker.ReportProgress(100);
}

void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Access Main UI Thread here
  progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void BackgroundWorkerCompletedEventHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Always check e.Cancelled and e.Error before checking e.Result!
   //even though I'm skipping that here
  var operationSuccessFul = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Result);
  if(operationSuccessFul)
   MessageBox.Show("I am Done");
}
```

You will get a call in BackgroundWorkerCompletedEventHandler function when you are done. You should display your progress bar in BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged event handler

Comment: I saw that but can you show me what you would add in the RunWorkerCompleted event?

Comment: Do whatever you wish to do, if you wish to show a message box, just do Messagebox.Show("Done"); in bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted Event handler

Comment: I'm sorry but RunWorkerCompleted would fire but when? I'm a little confused about the specifics on how it would know when progressBar1.Value is progressBar1.Maximum

Comment: I have just updated the code to give you a complete example which copies  lotof files in the background and updates the progressbar , and once it is done, it will display a message box that "I am Done".

Comment: You're updating the progressbar. I don't want to UPDATE IT. I just want to read the value and then find out when it's finished

Comment: Then you dont need ProgressChanged Event, Comment that out.BackgroundWorkerCompletedEventHandler will get called when your BackgroundWorkerDoWork returns

Comment: I updated my code and nothing happens. See my above question for the updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70730/discussion-between-pankaj-and-software-is-fun).

Answer (score 1):

You should think the other way round: Create a central "Progress class". This class is responsible for:

1. Update the progress bar
2. Show a MessageBox if certain conditions are met

Or to put it another way: its not the responibility of the progressbar to ... do something else than showing progress.